# Regex truncating end of string

Tags: .net, regex, nintex-workflow

For some reason my data is getting truncated at the end and I'm unsure as to why. I'm using Nintex Workflow RegEx action to extract my data which comes in two types

```
1. Who or Who: Something
2. When or When: 150845Z - 161045Z Jan 16
3. Where or Where: Around the world
```

Then I use the following

```
(?<=When:\s).*
```

In my online test it shows as it capturing [RegEx Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3DWhen%3A%5Cs).*&i=Who%3A%20Something%20is%20here%0D%0AWhen%3A%20123456Z%20-%20123456Z%20APR%2016%0D%0AWhere%3A%20Around%20the%20world). The problem occurs when I run this in Nintex Workflow. I get the following output `150845Z - 161045Z Jan 1=`

Is this a Nintex problem or my RegEx?

EDIT

To further clarify I have the following data can be received.[Data Capture](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3C%3dWhen%3a+*%29.%2b%28%3f%3d[%5Cr%5Cn]*%5Cd%2b.%5Cs*Where%29&i=1.+When%3a+1234567Z+-+1234567Z+Apr+16%0D%0A2.+Where%3a+Around%0D%0A%0D%0AWhen%3a+1234567Z+-+1234567Z+Apr+16%0D%0AWhere%3a+Around) I'm current doing the following `(?<=When:[^\S\r\n]*)[^\r\n]+|(?<=When: *).+(?=[\r\n]*\d+\.\s*Where)` The reason for this is the data might come in as

```
2. When: 150845Z - 161045Z Jan 16
3. Where: Around
```

or

```
When: 150845Z - 161045Z Jan 16
Where: Around
```

I can't control how the data is being received. I know now that I need to start the capture after `When:\s` and stop on `3. Where:` or `Where:`

Comment: What output do you get for a negative lookbehind `(?<!When:\s).*`?

Comment: Interesting, what if you use `(?<=When:\s).*$` or `(?m)(?<=When:\s).*$`? Are you using `extract` or `replace`?

Comment: The information from `Who:` to `When:\s` is removed. However after that everything is captured

Comment: There is no info about any specific regex  behavior in nintex, so, perhaps, the issue is with the tool itself. As far as I see, the match value is returned, thus, your pattern looks OK. You may try variations like `(?<=When:\s*).+` or `(?<=When:[^\S\r\n]*)[^\r\n]+`, too.

Comment: Still nothing? You want to get the string `150845Z - 161045Z Jan 16`? Maybe you need both lookarounds: `(?<=When:\s*).*(?=\r?\n\s*Where:)`

Comment: I was thinking the same thing when I left work. I will give this a try when I get back in. I think the problem lies with the Action I use to gather the information. I think it formats it incorrectly.

Comment: One problem with the test is sometimes there might be this type of input. `1. When and 4. Where` how do I account for that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *`1. When and 4. Where`*, please precise in the question body.

Comment: The capture that you provided me will stop since the input is `3. Where` not `Where`

Comment: [`(?<=When:[^\S\r\n]*)[^\r\n]+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3dWhen%3a%5b%5e%5cS%5cr%5cn%5d*)%5b%5e%5cr%5cn%5d%2b&i=1.+Who+or+Who%3a+Something%0d%0a2.+When+or+When%3a+150845Z+-+161045Z+Jan+16%0d%0a3.+Where+or+Where%3a+Around+the+world) should work, if not, try [`(?<=When: *).+(?=[\r\n]*\d+\.\s*Where)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3dWhen%3a+*).%2b(%3f%3d%5b%5cr%5cn%5d*%5cd%2b%5c.%5cs*Where)&i=1.+Who+or+Who%3a+Something%0d%0a2.+When+or+When%3a+150845Z+-+161045Z+Jan+16%0d%0a3.+Where+or+Where%3a+Around+the+world).

Comment: This answer worked